# I am changing indexing of Cosmos DB but it is not working as it is supposed to be

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am Using Azure SQL API and my data is structured in the following way:

```
{
"deviceId": "123_123",
"comms": 0,
"engineSpdEnc": 0,
"currentTime": 1542185998605,
"deviceName": "mydevice2",
"siteId": 0,
"messageType": 2,
"data": {

    "v5B3Freq": 0,
    "v5B3Amp": 0,
    "v5B4Freq": 0,
    "v5B4Amp": 0,
    "v5B5Freq": 0,
    "v5B5Amp": 0,
    "v6B6Freq": 0,
    "v6B6Amp": 0,
    "v6B7Freq": 0,
    "v6B7Amp": 0,
    "inletPres": 0
},
"EventProcessedUtcTime": "2018-11-14T09:01:42.6897624Z",
"PartitionId": 1,
"EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2018-11-14T08:59:58.645Z",
"IoTHub": {
    "MessageId": null,
    "CorrelationId": null,
    "ConnectionDeviceId": "device1",
    "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "636758197942626855",
    "EnqueuedTime": "2018-11-14T08:59:58.649Z",
    "StreamId": null
},
"id": "1734dd0c-1bb5-d424-4946-e2c957bb3858",
"_rid": "lblPAOEu3xYCAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/lblPAA==/colls/lblPAOEu3xY=/docs/lblPAOEu3xYCAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"08008e15-0000-0000-0000-5bebe47c0000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1542186108    }
```

And by using Azure portal I have changed the indexing policy from default to following:

```
{
"indexingMode": "lazy",
"automatic": false,
"includedPaths": [
    {
        "path": "/*",
        "indexes": [
            {
                "kind": "Range",
                "dataType": "Number",
                "precision": 3
            },
            {
                "kind": "Range",
                "dataType": "String",
                "precision": 3
            },
            {
                "kind": "Spatial",
                "dataType": "Point"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"excludedPaths": [
    {
        "path": "/data/*"
    }
]
}
```

According to this I have disable auto indexing policy and excluded the path in the `/data/*`   that means 
If I am going to query:

```
select * from c where c.data.v6B7Amp = 0
```

It should return nothing to me as there is no indexing for`c.data.pressure` , but I am getting all the records supposed to be in it.

Is it because I am using Azure portal to changing the indexing or anything else?

Comment: Indexing !== Filtering :).

Comment: Did you give some time to the indexing process to complete? Whenever you change the indexing policy everything has to be reindexed and included/excluded from scratch, and based on your database's size, this can take time.

Comment: I know it is not filtering but cosmos DB is tree based indexed database .as a result when we keep c.data.pressure it should not able to find in where condition.   I want to have complete manual indexing where only top level is indexed so that write throghput is more.

Comment: My collection is empty . changed the policy and uploaded the json file and checked it.@NickChapsas

Comment: @NickChapsas , I am right to expect  ....the behavior to give no results for where filtering of c.data.pressure < 25 ..

Comment: You are, but let me clear something out. Can you post your actual indexing policy? This one is not properly pasted so I cannot try to recreate this locally.

Comment: @NickChapsas i have updated my original JSON and indexing policy

Comment: @NickChapsas did you tried out locally ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't need to turn `automatic` indexing off or set the `indexingMode` to `lazy`, unless you have a reason to.

It appears that equality checks can work even if the path is excluded.
Where the excluded path will kick in is when you try to do something like an `order by` against that field.

Here is an example using your data data and your indexing policy:

[image]

Comment: Reason i am looking to off all the indexes is so that , my throughput of insertion increases from Azure Stream analytics JOB. As my Edge Device is sending 20 messages at a given time it is showing throttled Cosmos DB service . I feel too much of indexing as i have 150 sensors in it.   I am just wondered cosmos DB can't even write 20 messages per connection each record of size 8KB size ... that too from azures Stream analytics JOB service only

Comment: @AmjathKhan With automatic indexing turned off, you can still selectively add specific items to the index, but it's unclear if you're doing so, that's why I raised it.

Comment: In my Edge Device I am collection 20 device data but that data each message i cannot partition by device-id as ( only sending data to Event Hub can be partition Key ) added at sender's side. From Stream Analytics job i am pushing data to COSMOS DB ..   How can i improve performance of Cosmos DB

Comment: @AmjathKhan I can't answer that in an answer comments. you'd have to ask a new question specific to this new problem. I only answered the indexing question here. Feel free to open a new one explaining your problem in detail and we'll get back to you

Comment: Can you help me with sample how can i add selective item to index with automatic index off ..  @Nick

Comment: @AmjathKhan Sure, you can find the example in the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/ga-ie/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-indexing-policy#manage-indexing-using-azure-sdks

Comment: When we remove automatic indexing Order By clause wont work on any item
I tried with below having indexing above .. but no records shown 
SELECT * FROM c
ORDER BY c._ts DESC

Comment: @AmjathKhan It won't work unless you index the item. The `_ts` meta property is a different story all together. It should not be used for ordering purposes.

Comment: but in the include path i have give /* and exclude path /data/* .. that means everything else is included right ...

Comment: Yes but not automatically, because you turned that off.

Comment: @AmjathKhan - Please refrain from extended conversations in comments, as this is not what comments are for. If you have additional questions, please post as such, as Nick already suggested.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Sorry. I will do that . Thank you Nick.

Answer (score 1):

When a path is excluded from indexing, query will fallback to do a full scan of all the documents in the collection to filter the results. That's the reason you are seeing results for your query.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `"path": "/data/?"` The question mark refers to the specific value of the path, whereas the asterisk represents one or more paths as determined by the wildcard.